# How can I generate a random item from this element by calling the function?

Tags: python, function, random

I'm trying to get a random item from this list by calling the function that I made for it.
Nothing is working.

```
import random
def ColorText(colorText):
    colorText = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Black', 'Brown', 'Purple',
                 'Gray', 'Orange']

print(ColorText(random.choice(colorText)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The list `colorText` is only available in `ColorText()`, so you need to re-arrange your code to e.g.:

```
import random
def ColorText():
    colorText = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Black', 'Brown', 'Purple',
                 'Gray', 'Orange']
    return random.choice(colorText)

print(ColorText())
```